# Can someone explain to me using Grahams Law Why $\rm CO_2$ leaks out of a bike Tyre faster than $\rm O_2$?

Tags: thermodynamics, pressure

Just trying to work out ideal gas to use in this situation for a project

Comment: Hello Helen Macky... Your question lacks focus. You should provide some information as to what you have tried, what you struggle with, what are the parameters of your problem and, in general, as much information as you can. This will help people provide  correct answers that solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Graham's law of effusion is not an absolute.  It is a general trend, but the rate of permeation of a gas through a solid is dependent on the chemistry and properties of each, and ultimately derived through test data.

Parker Hannifin has an O-ring handbook available on their website.   If you search for "permeation" you will see a table with a wide variety of gases and elastomers. You can look at the permeation constants (higher number means more permeation) to find overall comparative performance of various gases, and choose a gas that seems best for you (to get a rough idea anyway).